# Why is this React.useEffect() code not safe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to understand [React.useEffect() in the official React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-skip-an-effect-on-updates#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies).

There I came across this under the question 'Is it safe to omit functions from the list of dependencies?':

```
function Example({ someProp }) {
  function doSomething() {
    console.log(someProp);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomething();
  }, []); //  This is not safe (it calls `doSomething` which uses `someProp`)
}
```

The explanation is somewhat limited. Why is it not safe?

Isn't 'props' immutable? Why should it be in the depedencies list?

Also, what 'function' should be there in the list of dependencies? Why is it not called 'props' instead?

Comment: I believe, the point is to declare your effects-functions inside the hook body, so that you keep track of what those functions accept as parameters within dependencies array. Otherwise, you may miss some dependencies and your effect function is not going to get fired, when expected.

Comment: In your example, the effect will run only once while first render, as the dependency array is empty. You can leave `doSomething()` function outside the `useEffect()` hook but in order to call it with new `someProp`, add `someProp` to the dependency array. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9dxrjh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useEffect hook is multipurpose. Its use is not limited to only one.
You can use useEffect for

1. as componentDidMount
2. as componentReceiveProps
3. as componenetDidUnmount

To answer your this questions:
what 'function' should be there in the list of dependencies?

the function which you think are gonna change refereence, or functions whose reference gonna change in future(generally the functions which you receive via props) are meant to go inside dependency list.

Why is it not called 'props' instead?
because `dependency` is more descriptive about useEffect. as useEffect is dependent on the array. useEffect will be called again and again if anything on the dependency list changes. That's why.

Isn't 'props' immutable? Why should it be in the depedencies list?
so that useEffect know when to re-call itself. So that you can call a method again when prop changes.

For Example
you have a list of product and aside it you are showing description. Not if you only pass id as a prop, your description won't be updated.
To update description you may leverage the dependency array,

Answer (score 0):

This is because someProp could be changed at any point and your function inside useEffect wouldn't know about it.

```
function Example({ someProp = 1 }) {
  someProp = 2;
  function doSomething() {
    console.log(someProp);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomething();
  }, []); 

  function someOtherFunction() {
    someProp = 3;
  }

}
```

In the example above your useEffected is not affected by the change in someProp, and only logs `2` even if it is changed by someOtherFunction elsewhere on code.

Generally you should just declare the required function inside the use effect itself.

```js
function Example({ someProp = 1 }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function doSomething() {
      console.log(someProp);
    }
    doSomething();

  }, [someProp]); 

  
  function someOtherFunction() {
    someProp = 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't change the props like that, can we?

Comment: It is a bad practice but you can change that, yes. also instead of some prop could be someState and there might be setSomeState elsewhere which changes the state.